# Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I would like to get results by query this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT id, subject
   FROM mailboxes
   WHERE tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('avail')
   ) AS t1
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This works and return rows with `tsv` containing *'Available'*. But if I use *'avai'* (truncating '...lable') it does not find anything.

Do all queries have to be in dictionary? Can't we just query such letters? I have a table that contains e-mail bodies (content) and I would like to make queries fast as it grows rapidly. Currently, I am using:

```
... WHERE content ~* 'avail'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Do all queries have to be in dictionary?

No. Because only word stems (according to the used [text search configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS)) are in the index to begin with. But more importantly:

**No**. Because, on top of that [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) is also [capable of ***prefix matching***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#textsearch-parsing-queries):

This would work:

```
SELECT id, subject
FROM   mailboxes
WHERE  tsv @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'avail:*')
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```

Note **3** things:

1. Use `to_tsquery()`, not `plainto_tsquery()`, in this case because ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#textsearch-parsing-queries)):

   > ... `plainto_tsquery` will not recognize `tsquery` operators, weight labels, or prefix-match labels in its input
2. Use the `'simple'` text search configuration to generate the `tsquery` since you obviously want to take the word *'avail'* as is and not apply stemming.
3. Append **`:*`** to make it a prefix search, i.e find all lexemes starting with 'avail'.

Important: This is a prefix search on lexemes (word stems) in the document. A regular expression match without wildcards (`content ~* 'avail'`) is not exactly the same! The latter is not left-anchored (to the start of lexemes) and would also find *'FOOavail'* etc.

It's unclear whether you want the behavior outlined in your query or the equivalent of the added regular expression. Trigram indexes using the additional module ([`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)) are the right tool for that. There are many related questions on dba.SE, [try a search](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20pg_trgm).

Overview:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

#### Demo

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('Zend has no framework')
   , ('Zend Framework')
   ) sub(t), to_tsvector(t) AS tsv
WHERE  tsv @@ to_tsquery('zend <-> fram:*');
```

```
 id |       t        |          tsv
----+----------------+------------------------
  2 | Zend Framework | 'framework':2 'zend':1
```

Related answer (chapter *"Different approach to optimize search"*):

- [How can I generate all trailing substrings following a delimeter?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157542/how-can-i-generate-all-trailing-substrings-following-a-delimeter/157653#157653)

#### Emails?

Since you mentioned emails, be aware that the text search parser identifies emails and does not split them into separate words / lexemes. Consider:

```
SELECT ts_debug('english', 'xangr@some.domain.com')
```

> ```
> (email,"Email address",xangr@some.domain.com,{simple},simple,{xangr@some.domain.com})
> ```

I would replace the separators `@` and `.` in your emails with space (`' '`) to index contained words.

Also, since you are dealing with *names* in emails, not with English (or some other language) *words*, I would use the `'simple'` text search configuration to disable stemming and other *language* features:

Build the `ts_vector` column with:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', translate('joe.xangr@some.domain.com', '@.', '  ')) AS tsv;
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer for this because either way because I'm clearly wrong for the first time ever and I'd rather not be reminded of it. I have two questions for you 1) where is `:*` documented, and 2) shouldn't a mention to build `to_tsvector('simple'..)` come hand-in-hand with instructions that future querying of that tsv will require the 'simple' configuration too to tsquery? I think you should clarify the ramifications of disabling stemming on a tsvector/tsquery.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Using the 'simple' configuration is not *required*. It just avoids stemming (like 'rats' to 'rat') which may or may not be desirable. Not desirable for the given example. Manual: I've added links above...

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Aside: Thinking you're wrong the *first* time ever, would be the second time. And that would be wrong, recursively. ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Wow, your way just gave me a full speed search. Before your way it tooks `0.380ms` to get result. After your way it took `0.079 ms`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Is there any way to wildcard before any word? Like `*vail*`...? Or something like `*:vail:*` I couldn't find any proper doc. about this. Maybe looking into wrong pages and don't want to open other question as its regarding to same question. Thanks.

Comment: @xangr: No, FTS only offers *prefix* matching for lexemes. For anything more, look to `pg_trgm`. FTS is faster (with a smaller index). You can even combine both indexes ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is still unable to make suffix/middle matching fror lexems?

Comment: @HmidiSlim: There were no functional changes for text search in Postgres 10 (that I am aware of) except that it now also works for JSON and JSONB.

Comment: begin with postgres11, we can use starts_with, might be faster than full text search. if just  for prefix search.