# How to make middle and suffix matching using full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to find a string on a database using FTS on Postgres:

```
select name
from users
where to_tsvector('simple', name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'ad:*')
```

But the `:*` search only the words start with ad.

I found this question Get partial match from [Get partial match from GIN indexed `TSVECTOR` column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column) column.

But it doesn't mention how to solve the problem of middle and suffix matching using FTS?

Answer (score 7):

The "Full" in Full Text Search means match full words, not parts of words

You should use RegExp or LIKE or tri-gram matching instead

You *can* mimic suffix matching by reversing words in your index and also reversing your queries, but this takes more space:

```
select
reverse('brown fox')::tsvector @@ (reverse('rown') || ':*')::tsquery --true
```

Comment: but it does search prefixes. `to_tsquery('pre:*')`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that that is possible with FTS.  It seems like a better job for `pg_trgm`, which can accelerate `like` and `ilike` (and their symbolic forms, ~~ and ~~*).

Comment: Based on [Fast Search Using PostgreSQL Trigram Indexes ](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/) I tried to use `pg_trgm` on a table containig 12165 rowsand the result give me a response time shorter when I call `like` operator without the index but when invoking an index I got a time longer than the first.

Comment: Did you VACUUM ANALYZE after building the index?  What was the argument to the LIKE?  What was the "explain analyze"?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT name FROM users where name like '%ada%' `